# Adding shipping total is making my data inflate

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add everything in te data (dollar_value_us, QUANTITY) but not add shipping total since each transaction number has multiple items but the customer only paid shipping once. I am using the below data:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=01693db7ce05b062804cedeb3b3a7e73

below is the query which I am using on my actual databse:

```
select QUARTER_DATE ,COUNTRY,sum(DOLLAR_VALUE_US), sum(QUANTITY), max(SHIPPING_TOTAL)
from transaction_detail_mv
group by QUARTER_DATE,COUNTRY
```

the final output for usa should have shipping total amount of 35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Max(ShippingTotal)` instead of `Sum` so that you only get the shipping total once per order.

See this modification to your dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=96827f2a82976bdf5f07d8d1831f391c

Comment: I am also trying to join the transactions table to fiscal calendar table and country table so that my output is grouped by country and fiscal month. When I am using the max function, it is only giving me the max value of 1 of the transactions. it should be giving me the max value of each transaction and adding it together.

Comment: Yeah, the solution I gave will only work on the example you provided, where you're grouping by Transaction Number.  I'd recommend taking the results of that query and summing from there to get the country-level rollup.

Comment: I edited my question can you look at it again pleaeeeee :)

Comment: Hi @SomiyaL, generally you should post a new question rather than editing an existing one if the edits you're going to make substantially change the issue, rather than clarifying.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266140/should-i-edit-my-question-or-create-a-new-one, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295359/should-this-edit-be-a-new-question, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions